# Xamarin Forms Location with Full features

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Hi I am trying to build one Application in Xamarin forms which has huge dependency  on location services.

Using Xamarin.Essentials I am able to get the location, but in Android its give the last known location and sometime its not that much accurate.

Problem 1.

But I am not able to add Location Listener so that once user change location, I can get notified.

Problem 2.
How to exactly know whether user has disabled Phone Location or App Location ?

Please guide me.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem #1**

I don't know, but i think Xamarin.Essentials doesn't have Location Listener feature yet, might be wrong, but you can use this [plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin) from jamesmontemagno (also a main developer of Xamarin.Essentials), this plugin can track geolocation changes like this:

```
CrossGeolocator.Current.IsListening
```

**Problem #2**

Following the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android), you receive an exception for the following cases: permission was not granted or if the location is not enabled/supported

```
try
{
    var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();

    if (location != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Latitude: {location.Latitude}, Longitude: {location.Longitude}, Altitude: {location.Altitude}");
    }
}
catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
{
    // Handle not supported on device exception
}
catch (FeatureNotEnabledException fneEx)
{
    // Handle not enabled on device exception
}
catch (PermissionException pEx)
{
    // Handle permission exception
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Unable to get location
}
```

Comment: forgive relive the ask, but Is there still no such function in xamarin essentials?

Comment: @Frnk a quick check on the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android) and it seems it still doesn't have that feature