# Xamarin Forms - Geofencing library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, geolocation, geofencing

I have created a xamarin mobile application and want to create the following feature: Create one or more geofences. When the user with the phone is at the location, I want to trigger some code. Are there any libraries that I can use to implement this cross platform with xamarin forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Geofence is a Circular Shape, you can use [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/) to get the [distance between 2 points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.location.calculatedistance?view=xamarin-essentials), and if the Distance is Smaller than the Geofence Distance, it's inside the Geofence.

```
long geofenceDistance = 2;
Location geofenceCentercordinate = new Location(centrerCoordinate.Latitude, centrerCoordinate.Longitude);
Location userLocation = new Location(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
var distance = (long)Location.CalculateDistance(userLocation ,geofenceCentercordinate, DistanceUnits.Kilometers);
if(distance < geofenceDistance){
    //it's inside the Geofence
}
```

Also, if you want constant listening of your location you can check my other anwser [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56023377/8182493).

Comment: Thank for your help. Do you know which xamarin.essentials I need for this?

Comment: @MYil If you use the latest version you will definitly have this, i'm glad i could help, if this solved your issue, don't forget to mark it as the correct anwser

Comment: @MYil also don't forget you can change the DistanceUnits.Kilometers to what unit fits your purpose, i also added a link to other question where i anwser how to listen to location changes, but i guess you don't need a location change everytime

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your solution is to get the distance between two points, but I really need to know how to create a geofence and I couldn't find that in your reaction. Hope you can help me out with this one.

Comment: Ok can you be more specific on the type of Geofencing you are looking for?

Comment: Is it a Polygon in a map? is just programatically?

Comment: if it's circular

Comment: So can you tell me what type of geofening you are looking for?

Comment: I am looking for a circle geofence with a radius around 50 meters. It is just programatically, when the user is in the region I only want to print something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209437/discussion-between-ricardo-dias-morais-and-m-yil).

Comment: Do you maybe know if I should use a timer to get the location each 10 sec or should I use something else to achieve this?